# Use regex to capture next line of text after newline

Tags: javascript, regex

Sample text:

```
First line of text.

Second line of text with a newline here
that continues here. I need to capture this last line.
```

This is my first regex. Here's where my brain stopped working:

```
\n([^>]+)>
```

It captures all the way back to the first newline at the end of the "First line of text."

I'm not coding, I'm using a module that accepts expressions, so, using regex only, without methods, How do I work back from the ">" to either

1. The beginning of the line or
2. The newline preceding this line

Comment: From your example, what you need is the `that continues here. I need to capture this last line.`? Or just the `I need to capture this last line.`?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `[^>]` matches newline characters. If you remove newlines from the character class it should work:

```
([^>\n]+)>
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` captures beginning of a line

`$` captures the end of a line

`^.*$\n` will capture an entire line and its line break (line break must exist for this to capture)

Comment: Other way round - `$` is end; `^` is start.

Comment: This works, but possibly not for the reason you think. The `^` can match at the start of the string. The only reason it doesn't match from the start of the string is that `.` doesn't match newlines. At least, that's the default behaviour in javascript. But the `[^>]` in the question can match newlines.